# Why does my container not return to a pre-hover state on mouse out?

Tags: css

I created a [menu](http://andylilien.com/index_new.html) that slides in on hover.

When i move the mouse away from the menu it doesn't return to the pre hover state even though I've specified the container width and height so anywhere the mouse moves outside that it should return.

```
#menucontrol {  
width:500px;
height: 800px;
}
#menucontrol:hover #navdiv {    
left: 23px;
transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
opacity: 1.0; 
}
#menucontrol:hover #dashes {     
transform: rotate(360deg);  
transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
opacity: 0;
}
#navdiv {
position: absolute;
top: 68px;
left:-55px;
z-index:999999;
opacity: 0;
width: 555px;
transition: all .3s ease-in-out;    
}
```

Comment: Hey Reelhero. Please edit your question to include the relevant HTML *in the question itself*. External websites can go down which would unfortunately render the question useless to future readers.

Comment: I took a quick peek at your page. You have an element `fluid_container2` that covers the entire page. This element is a *child* of your `#menucontrol`. Hovering over a child element will always trigger the `:hover` state of the parent. I've made a [quick example here](https://jsfiddle.net/jkebo062/) to show this.

Comment: thank you Tyler - I tried to add the html but it just shows up as links. To your point that fluid_container2 is the slideshow background. How do i "unchild" it...? the #menucontrol should be closed before the fluid_container2 begins..

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question: *" the #menucontrol should be closed before the fluid_container2 begins"*. Rather than (pseudo) `<menu control> <fluid_container2 /> </menu control>`, you should have `<menu control /> <fluid_container2 />`. It seems as though your HTML is simply structured incorrectly.

Comment: i think you are right thats definitely a big part of the problem because i just created another version http://andylilien.com/index_new88.html without the slideshow background and it works fine

Comment: Yup! Try taking your slideshow background portion and sticking it after you close the `menu control` div. Like `<div id="menucontrol"> ... </div> <div id="fluid_container2"> ... </div>`. You may need to tidy up some CSS but this is likely what you'll have to do to resolve the issue. You could add `pointer-events: none;` to the `fluid_container2` instead of all that, however then your child links wouldn't work.

Comment: Tyler! you rock. worked like a charm http://andylilien.com/index_new.html     but ,now for a wrench in the works - the right way to do this is to have you roll over the "menu dashes" and the menu slides in - as it is its the whole menucontrol div..so if you get anywhere close it slides in - the problem with that is once the navigation menu is up if you roll away from where the dashes were the menu disappears..

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is happening is that your #menucontrol div is taking up the entire page except for the area of your logo. I would suggest trying the :hover psuedo element on your #dashes id. I also noticed your z-indexes are set on some elements and not others. I think this could also be causing you some issues. Without seeing your html it is hard to duplicate and make changes to help you solve this issue.

Comment: thank you! you're right i haven't added z-indexes to some.. i did try adding the :hover pseudo element to the #dashes but it wouldn't work for some reason - and apologies for not adding the html when i put it in only the links show up not the html.. ill investigate why I got that wrong..